# Topological Derivation of Leray Spectral Sequence

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

I'm interested in computing - to the extent possible - the Leray spectral sequence for a particular map which is *almost*, but not quite, a fiber bundle (e.g. a Seifert fiber space). The hardest step currently is writing down the edge maps on the $E_2$ page.

Can someone point me to a reference that derives the Leray sequence from a topological/geometric point of view (i.e. not by appealing to the Grothendieck spectral sequence)? I recall reading somewhere that a CW-structure on the base space can induce the needed filtration, but the reference I found (which I can't remember now) only did this for the case of an actual fiber bundle.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the Grothendieck spectral sequence? Intuitively it should generalize much more easily than any topological method. The topological method is usually used only for the special case of fiber bundles and local coefficients (that is locally constant sheaves) and I don't know how much of it can be generalized.

Comment: Indeed, the Grothendieck spectral sequence tells you that you need to understand the derived pushforward. In good cases (presumably including the one you're talking about) the derived pushforward of the constant sheaf isn't quite a local system but you can stratify the base so that it's a local system on each stratum (I.e. You have a constructible sheaf) and then you can try to compute from there.

Comment: Thanks! In my case, I understand the derived pushforward reasonably well. The thing I don't understand is the edge map itself, especially on the torsion subgroup. I know the form of the sequence, but the Grothendieck formalism makes it hard to see what the ($E_2$) maps are. I want something like the CW-complex answer for fibrations. (If it helps: in my case, all fibers are $S^1$, but they have multiplicity at some points)

Comment: I'm rather ignorant about 3-manifolds, but I thought a Seifert fiber space was an honest-to-God fiber bundle (tho' over an orbifold). And the sheaf-theoretic derivation/interpretation works just as well for orbifolds/stacks.

Comment: Any Serre fibration over a finite CW base is fiberwise weak equivalent to a fiber bundle. So I don't understand what the issue is....

Comment: @JohnKlein To the best of my knowledge, a Seifert fibration is an honest fibration in the orbifold sense. But it is not a Serre fibration if we regard the base as a CW complex in the naïve way. If you turn it into a fibre bundle, the fibre can be anything except $S^1$. Indeed, I would be happy to see a good geometric description of the homotopy fibre leading to the correct Leray-Serre spectral sequence.

Comment: @Sebastian Goette: I don't understand your qualm. the construction I have in mind is this: For any space $B$ Milnor gives an explicit construction of a universal principal bundle $U \to B$ with respect to a topological group $G$. Here $U$ is contractible. If $E \to B$ is a any Serre fibration we can form the fiber product $F:= E \times^{B} U$. Then $F$ comes equipped with a (free) $G$-action and the Borel construction $EG\times_G F \to BG$ is a fiber bundle that is fiber homotopy equivalent to the original fibration $E \to B$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Bott and Tu](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/botttu.pdf) do this in their book *Differential forms in algebraic topology*, see Section 14, ``Leray's construction" (starting on page 179).

Comment: Wonderful: exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realize they did the general case there.

Answer (score 1):

One such reference is

[Segal's "Classifying Spaces and Spectral Sequences"](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/PMIHES/PMIHES_1968__34_/PMIHES_1968__34__105_0/PMIHES_1968__34__105_0.pdf)

See proposition 5.2.